# BrotherDCP-9045CDN scan to subnetwork

Tags: networking, subnet, printer, network-printer

I'm trying to set up a BrotherDCP-9045CDN which is shared between 2 network (See [Accessing printer from another subnet](https://serverfault.com/questions/104183/accessing-printer-from-another-subnet) for the network topology).

The printer and scan functions are accessible from both networks (only through IP from 192.168.1.XX hosts) but now I want to use the brscan-skey tool which permit to scan being physically in front of the printer and sending the scan output to a PC. When brscan-skey daemon is launched on a PC, for example PC2, it then communicate its presence on the network to the printer (maybe providing its IP) and then I can select on the printer screen to send scan output to PC2. That works for PC on the same network as the printer but failed with PCs on 192.168.1.XX. I can still see that they are registered on the printer but when I try to scan to them, the printer blocks displaying "connection to PC".

How can I configure the second router to let the printer communicate with the PCs on the other network (appart from the printer I don't want other PC in 192.168.0.XX to be able to see or interact with those in  192.168.1.XX) ? More generally is my setup correct or should I use VLANs, different masqs, put the printer in DMZ, etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know some printer software communicates to printers on the network using their MAC address. This would be inaccessible through a router. It may also be that the firewall in the DD-WRT might be blocking the traffic. If you could monitor the traffic on the 0.xx network while the PC is talking to the printer this would help in figuring out what protocols are being used.

VLANs would act the same as having separate physical networks so that would not change the situation. You could put all the computers on the same physical network and still use the different IP subnets. This would allow the layer2 communication but somewhat* prevent communication between the PCs on different networks.

*If someone manually changed their IP to the other subnet they would be able to access it.

Comment: It was the firewall of DD-WRT.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to me that it's either a routing issue or a firewall issue. Does the scanner\printer have a default gateway configured in it's network settings? What protocol does it use to transmit data: HTTP, FTP, SMTP, RPC, etc.?